# change background of table cell depending on value

Tags: jquery, html, css, model-view-controller

I have a slight issue, slightly different from the usual background color change questions. Mine refers to the @html.displayfor instead of the usual value in td element.

I have tried implementing a jquery script which will change the colour of the High Priority cell if the value of that cell equals to Yes. I tried implementing a class into the displayfor, but it doesnt seem to make a difference. Below is my section of code in question.

table.js

```
   window.onload = function () {
    $("#tfhover").hide().fadeIn(1500);
    var tfrow = document.getElementById('tfhover').rows.length;
    var tbRow = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < tfrow; i++) {
        tbRow[i] = document.getElementById('tfhover').rows[i];
        tbRow[i].onmouseover = function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
        };
        tbRow[i].onmouseout = function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = '#d4e3e5';
        };

            if ($('#high').val() == 'Yes') {
                this.style.backgroundColor = "#000033";
            };
        };
    };
```

index.cshtml

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Table.js"></script>



<table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">  
    <tr>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JobID) &nbsp&nbsp
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Order.OrderID) &nbsp&nbsp
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location.LocationName) &nbsp&nbsp
        </th>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Order.EstimatedCompletion) &nbsp&nbsp
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HighPriority) &nbsp&nbsp
        </th>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastUpdated) &nbsp&nbsp
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comments)  &nbsp&nbsp
        </th>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)  &nbsp&nbsp
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
          <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Order.OrderID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.LocationName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Order.EstimatedCompletion)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HighPriority, new {@class ="high" })
        </td>
          <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastUpdated)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
        </td>
           <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.JobID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.JobID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.JobID })
        </td>
    </tr>   
}
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you using the id selector '#high'. You should use the class selector based on the row you are looking at '.high'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you're using the `#` character instead of the `.` character for the class. Also it's not `val()` it's `text()` for `non-input elements`. Is there any `html` inside the `td`?

You cannot assign a class to anything w/o it being an `element`. Throw a `span` in there. Also you were going through the `<tr>` instead of the `<td>` to assign the backgorund color to.

Also needed another check on `mouseout` which checked to see if the text was `Yes` and the class was `high` so it didn't apply another `background color`.

jQuery

```
$(function () {
  if ($('.high').text() == 'Yes') {
      $('.high').parent().css('background-color', '#000033');
  }

  $("#tfhover")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500)
    .find('td')
    .hover(
       function () {
           $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
       }, 
       function () {
            if ($(this).children().hasClass('high') && $(this).children().text() == 'Yes') {
               $(this).css('background-color', '#000033');
            } else {
               $(this).css('background-color', '#d4e3e5');
            }
       }
    );
});
```

HTML

```
<table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">
 <tr>
    <th>JobID</th>
    <th>OrderID</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>EstimatedCompletion</th>
    <th>HighPriority</th>
    <th>LastUpdated</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>JobID</td>
    <td>OrderID</td>
    <td>LocationName</td>
    <td>EstimatedCompletion</td>
    <td><span class="high">Yes</span></td>
    <td>LastUpdated</td>
    <td>Comments</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: oh im only just noticing the # now , whoops ha there is no html inside the td by the way...after changing it to your redesign it still doesnt seem to change...

Comment: make a fiddle w/ the exact HTML (not the MVC) please